# Transfer data into sharepoint using ssis

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to transfer data from SSIS to SharePoint and place the csv in a sharepoint list.
I have tried automating this with ssis and for some reason when I execute the package under a scheduled task the package will not run....
If i create a scheduled task and run dtexec (and the package path) this will not run under the scheduled task but it will run if i am using a .bat file and enter the same command script..  I am using creds that have access to the sharepoint site.  It seems that there is just no way to automate placing csv files onto sharepoint.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/905fd9fb-ae70-4335-9628-d28d040f0bdc
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/d59bbc46-27b4-468e-9ed6-70435200bef2

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't had the need to use it in a production environment yet, I'm sure this custom component will suit your needs :)
http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharePoint List Destination&referringTitle=Home